# Django reverse 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to use reverse method in django view but I got an exception 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

here is my view

```
class AbandonTicketView(View):
    context = dict()
    template_name = "places/order_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token, ordercode):
        order = abandon_oder(uidb64, token, ordercode)
        if order is not None and order.paid is False:
            return reverse("order_detail", kwargs={"ordercode": order.code})
        return redirect("tickets")
```

view that I want to go:

```
class OrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = "places/order_detail.html"
    context = dict()

    def get(self, request, ordercode):
        order = Order.objects.get(code=ordercode)
        self.context["order"] = order
        self.context["key"] = settings.tycoon.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

        if order.send_count >= 3 and order.paid is False:
            self.context["abandon_ticket"] = "Order was canceled"
        return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=self.context)

    def post(self, request, ordercode):
        order = pay_for_ticket(ordercode, request.POST["stripeToken"], request.user)
        self.context["order"] = order
        return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=self.context)
```

here is url:

```
 path("orders/<code:ordercode>/detail/", views.OrderDetailView.as_view(), name="order_detail"),
 path("tickets/", views.OrderedTicketsView.as_view(), name="tickets"),
```

I don't really know why it happends, because I do the similar reverse earlier and everything  works fine, but not now. Could you help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace?

Answer (score 4):

`reverse()` returns a string, but your view has to return a `HttpResponse`.

Change your line:

```
return reverse("order_detail", kwargs={"ordercode": order.code})
```

to also use `redirect()` (like the other part of your view)

```
return redirect("order_detail", args=[order.code, ])
```

or maybe even simplified like this

```
return redirect("order_detail", order.code)
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `redirect` with reverse and it works.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect(reverse("order_detail", kwargs={"ordercode": order.code}))
```

OR the second keyword to do the same thing is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("order_detail", kwargs={"ordercode": order.code}))
```

The reasoning behind this is that reverse just returns the URL in the form of a string. When you want to redirect an HTTP Response should happen. Only cases where only the URL is required reverse should be used otherwise you need to generate an HTTP Response as well.